# Spring Boot Test model attribute does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockmvc

Im trying to test a controller, Author Controller, which returns a view with a model. The problem is on the testInitUpdateAuthor() test where its not able to find the model or attribute name specifically. All other methods are fine with their model/attribute tests.

Any advice?

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class AuthorController {

    private final AuthorService authorService;
    private final String CREATEORUPDATEFORM = "author/createOrUpdateAuthor";

    public AuthorController(AuthorService authorService) {
        this.authorService = authorService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/author/{id}/update")
    public String updateAuthor(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("author", authorService.findById(id));

        return CREATEORUPDATEFORM;
    }
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class AuthorControllerTest {

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    AuthorService authorService;

    @InjectMocks
    AuthorController authorController;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(authorController).build();
    }

    @Test
    void getIndex() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/author/index"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("author/index"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("authors"));
    }

    @Test
    void testInitUpdateAuthor() throws Exception {
        when(authorService.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Author.builder().id(1L).build());

        mockMvc.perform(get("/author/1/update"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("author/createOrUpdateAuthor"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("author"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `setUp` method, add `@Autowired` to the `MockMvc` field. You can remove the `AuthorController` field. Replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean`. Instead of `@SpringBootTest` you could use `@WebMvcTest(AuthorController.class)` to get a smaller (and thus faster) running test.

Comment: @M.Deinum That worked thank you and for the tips! Can you hazard a guess to why it wasn't working with my configuration?

Comment: Because you didn't use the proper way. You used `@SpringBootTest` and then completly ignore it by using plain Mockito with `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`. Although you can get it to work with plain Mockito as well the `@WebMvcTest` makes that a little easier.

Comment: Wow completely didnt see that part. Thank you again